# when converting char array to string

Tags: c++

Let's say char array of 100 is made and a short string is allocated inside it.

Ex)

```
char a[100];
sprintf(a,"%d sized char",100);
string str(a);
```

(I know i can a[] = "some string"; but this is not the case and thing that im concerned with)

Then where does rest of the memories go? str wouldnt be saved with string and spaces behind it. Are they freed(?) Or ignored during conversion from char [] to str?

Btw. Can you also introduce me a reference or book to memories? I'm a heginner but they interest me but i can't get infos about them easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
char a[100] ;
```

you are allocating 100 bytes.

If you do this as a local variable

```
void somefunct () ;
{
   a[100] ;
}
```

The memory allocated to A will automatically be reclaimed. The allocation is made on the system stack.

Before calling somefunc ()

```
^  [Stack Memory Here]
[SP]
```

while executing some function()

```
A                             [Old SP Value]
                              [SP]
```

When somefunct completes

```
^    [A was out here]
[SP]
```

If you do it

```
a[100] ;
void somefunct () ;
{
}
```

The memory will remain allocated.

When you do

```
string str(a) ;
```

str makes a copy of the contents of A "100 sized char".

Also note that your string "%d sized char" also takes up memory that will not be deallocated.

Comment: ah...the stack and heap thing. I haven't learnt that yet. Only heard. So are you saying that even a is "100 sized char\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0..." after string str(a), str wil have "100 sized char" not, "100 sized char\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"?

Comment: That is correct. str will have a copy only containing the text. The extra data at the end will not be copied. Also keep in mind that, if you allocate on the stack (local variable), only the byte after "char" is guaranteed to have a zero (inserted by sprint). The rest of the bytes will have whatever values were left there in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`string` manages its part of the memory. When you do the conversion, `string` will copy your string. Notice that your `a` is not null terminated, might result in problems

Comment: In this way, your `a` is allocated on stack or RODATA, depending on where you put the definition. When you initialize `string`, it just copies a null terminated part of the `a`. So if your `a` is "Hello\0blablablabla", `string` just has the "Hello" part. "blablabla" part is not copied. But it still resides in your `a`. After initialization of `string`, `str` and `a` are independent. You could free one and won't affect the other (in this case you can't free `a`). I would recommend CSAPP. It's really comprehensive.

Comment: Actually his `a` is null-terminated, `sprintf` always null-terminates its output.

Comment: So are you saying that whether a is "Hello\0blablaalb" or "Hello\0\0\0\0", when a is converted to string by string str(a), str will have "Hello" and a will have whatever it had before?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks for noticing me of that! I confused it with the writing byte function.

Comment: @user3290525 Actually `string` has a method `c_str()` which will return a `const char*`. You can play with this to see what it holds actually. In short, `string` **copies** the original `char*`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your comments. I knew about c_str(). But I wanted to know what string prints after converting a char with bunch of uninitialized values.

Comment: You mean if `char* a` is uninitialized? Then `string str(a)` will read `a` character by character until it finds a `\0`. This is dangerous. If there is no `\0`, then it will probably trigger a segmentation fault (accessing addresses that are not mapped or don't have privilege to do so).

Comment: You could think it as (not actually so) `while(a != '\0') {appendToStr(a); ++a;}`.